# Insert at caret with javascript, but only within a certain class

Tags: javascript, range, selection

I'm using a bit of javascript written by <s>The Great and Powerful Oz</s> [Tim Down](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96100/tim-down) that inserts things at the caret. It works great, but how can I restrict the function to only operate within a div with a class name of "editor-text"?

Edit: It must also work within other elements (such as H1) that may be within the .editor-text div.

Edit2: Must also work on new lines. See http://jsfiddle.net/j5mv219L/

**The Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/wfo7gcvh/

**The Code:**

```
function pasteHtmlAtCaret(html) {
    var sel, range;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        // IE9 and non-IE
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();

            // Range.createContextualFragment() would be useful here but is
            // non-standard and not supported in all browsers (IE9, for one)
            var el = document.createElement("div");
            el.innerHTML = html;
            var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
                node, lastNode;
            while ((node = el.firstChild)) {
                lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
            }
            range.insertNode(frag);

            // Preserve the selection
            if (lastNode) {
                range = range.cloneRange();
                range.setStartAfter(lastNode);
                range.collapse(true);
                sel.removeAllRanges();
                sel.addRange(range);
            }
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        // IE < 9
        document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(html);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the node that has the selection, and check if it has the class or is the child of an element that has the class etc

```
function pasteHtmlAtCaret(html, selector) {
    var sel, range, parent, node = null;

    if (document.selection) {
        node = document.selection.createRange().parentElement();
    } else {
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
            node = selection.getRangeAt(0).startContainer;
            if (node !== $(node).closest(selector).get(0)) {
                node = node.parentNode;
            }
        }
    }



    if (node && $(node).closest(selector).length > 0 && window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();
            var el = document.createElement("div");
            el.innerHTML = html;
            var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
                node, lastNode;
            while ((node = el.firstChild)) {
                lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
            }
            range.insertNode(frag);

            if (lastNode) {
                range = range.cloneRange();
                range.setStartAfter(lastNode);
                range.collapse(true);
                sel.removeAllRanges();
                sel.addRange(range);
            }
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(html);
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/j5mv219L/1/)

Comment: Thanks adeneo, that does indeed work. I was hoping to just edit the original pasteHTMLAtCaret function, rather than the code that calls that function since it is used in several places though.

Comment: I know this was answered awhile back, but I discovered a bug with this method. Basically lets say you have an <h1> tag in there. You can't paste into it because it's reading the H1 as the parent, not the specified class: http://jsfiddle.net/kthornbloom/wfo7gcvh/4/

Comment: I had to remove this as the answer due to the problem with the solution. I can re-mark it if it's corrected.

Comment: So sorry, but I found another little issue. It doesn't work on new lines made with <br>'s. Any clues as to why? Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/j5mv219L/

Comment: Added a fix for that as well, but you really should ask a new question whenever the parameters of the original question changes like this, instead of just removing the accepted tag every time.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if it was better to have duplicate questions, or request edits here.

Comment: Neither am I, smaller edits to bugs in the code, like this was, is probably fine here, but generally it's reccommended to ask a new question if the question itself changes, I think?